# MVC PHP Pagination

Tags: php, pagination

I have been wreaking my brains on how I can paginate blog posts on my personal site. The structure of the site is MVC (Allowing me content manage it through the browser)

The Model:

```
function displayBlog()
{
  global $BEAR;

  $data = array();

$stmt = $BEAR->Database->query
("SELECT id, type, published_on, height, width, title, body FROM blog_posts ORDER BY id DESC");

$i = 0;

while($row = $stmt->fetch_assoc())
{

  $data[$i]['id'] = $row['id'];
  $data[$i]['title'] = $row['title'];
  $data[$i]['content'] = $row['content'];

  $i++;
}
 return $data;
}
```

This gathers the desired blog information from the database and this is passed to the Controller:

```
$data = $BEAR->Blog->displayBlog();
for($i=0, $i < count($data);$i++)
{
  $id = $data[$i]['id'];
  $title = $data[$i]['title'];
  $content = $data[$i]['content'];

  $result = $title;
  $result .= $content;
}
$BEAR->Template->setData('blog', $result, FALSE);
```

From the above code I just user the get data function to display the blog within my view, this works just fine. But I have no idea how I can paginate the results, if anyone can give me any form of guidance that would be great. Thanks guys.

Comment: `SELECT id, type, published_on, height, width, title, body FROM blog_posts ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 0,10` which will fetch results from 0 to 10. `LIMIT 10,10` will fetch from 10 to 20.... so on.... this is a starting point. Now think....

Comment: Does it your own MVC framework or one of community known framework?

Comment: None of this is related to MVC design pattern. Last time i heard, it did not stand for "my very code".

Comment: @itachi I understand I can limit the query, but I dont understand how I would go about doing the rest.

Comment: @semsesm The application is something that I have built.@teresko your comment is rather obtuse, the application is MVC... As im using a Model, View, Controller thankyou.

Comment: it will be a long code if need to be post from scratch. More importantly, tell us where you are stuck at. This will narrow down the needed coding. and teresko is right btw.

Comment: Surely its a form of MVC, if not what would it be stated as? In regards to pagination I have never done anything to warrant it, so this is my first time.

Comment: @HireLee If I am not mistaken - are you looking for a code snippet to display a list of linked available pages in your View ?